# warbled gems not seen by Rakefile

Tags: glassfish, warbler

I have s sinatra app warbled and deployed on glassfish. I have used bundler to manage dependencies and warbler has included those gems in WEB-INF/gems directory.

But when i try to run a rake task from WEB-INF directory, that task is not running.

```
gfish@server2:~/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/sinatra_app/WEB-INF$ rake resque:work
(in /home/gfish/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/sinatra_app/WEB-INF)
rake aborted!
Could not find gem 'sinatra (>= 0, runtime)' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.
/home/gfish/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/sinatra_app/WEB-INF/Rakefile:5:in `(root)'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

gfish@server2:~/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/sinatra_app/WEB-INF$ **ls -l** gems/gems/
total 104
...
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 2011-02-24 14:38 sinatra-1.1.3
```

Comment: In my rakefile its referring to Bundler.setup and from there its trying to require the 'sinatra' gem, but not sure why the gem is not available to the rakefile or bundler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found it. I used the following code to do it.

```
# Add warbled gems to the $LOAD_PATH
if ENV['RACK_ENV'] == "production"
  puts "Adding warbled gems to the load path..."
  local_gems_path = Dir[File.expand_path(".") + "/gems/gems/*"]
  local_gems_path.each do |g|
    $LOAD_PATH.unshift "#{g}/lib/"
  end
end
```